# Updating a single row in a combobox from the database

Tags: c#, combobox

When I insert or update a new record I was for the user to be able to use the combobox immediately after and the record be there. I have the comboboxes filling on the pageload event. When they hit update or create it clears the old values and puts in the new ones it gets from the database. My question is how can you have it only update the combobox with the new row added or updated and not reload all the rows?

Here is my populate method:

```
List<LabelData> labelList = LabelData.getAllLabels();
            if (labelList != null)
        {
            foreach (LabelData l in labelList)
            {
                cmboBoxPreviousVersion.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", l.PackFormatID, l.Description));

            }
        }
```

Here is the .getAllLabels Method

```
            SqlConnection dbConn = null;
        List<LabelData> LabelList = new List<LabelData>();

        try
        {
            using (dbConn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default["tville"].ToString()))
            {
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM PFormat";

                SqlCommand cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();

                cmd.CommandText = sql;

                dbConn.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        LblD l = new LabelData();
                        l.PFormID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                        l.Descrip = reader.GetString(1);
                        l.StockID = reader.GetInt32(2);
                        l.PPC = reader.GetBoolean(3);
                        l.PP = reader.GetBoolean(4);
                        l.PW = reader.GetBoolean(5);
                        LabelList.Add(l);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return LabelList;
    }
```

Comment: Are you reloading the entire page after they submit?  What's your goal?  Save another trip to DB after insert/update or keep from reloading the entire page?  I recommend against managing data outside of your bindings because it adds unnecessary complexity.  Consider updating only the combo box upon submit using update panel or JQuery Ajax.

Comment: @StinkyTowel Not reloading entire page after they submit only the comboboxes. Goal is just to add the new field to the combobox instead of reloading it, if possible. I update on submit and not familiar with JQuery Ajax, and update panel?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?  Which flavor of Asp.Net?  Web forms, MVC, web pages, etc?

Comment: @StinkyTowel 4.0 not using asp.net and winforms.